# QTreeWidget выделение двух строк разными цветами разными кнопками мыши

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Использую QTreeWidget. Условия следующие:

- выделять можно только строки нижнего уровня
- выделенными одновременно могут быть только две строки
- при нажатии левой кнопкой мыши - строка выделяется одним цветом
- при нажатии правой кнопкой - другим цветом
- при повторном нажатии на строку - выделение отменяется
- рамки фокуса быть не должно

Это всё. Ищу решение попроще в том смысле, что не хотелось бы писать свой собственный model/view.

Что я пробовал делать:

попробовал написать свой QStyledItemDelegate и всё бы хорошо, но выделение происходит только для части строки. Не помню, как точно выглядел код, но суть вот такая

```
class ItemDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
    void paint(QPainter *painter,const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,const QModelIndex &index) const
    {
        QStyleOptionViewItem custom_option(option);

        if (custom_option.state.testFlag(QStyle::State_HasFocus))
            custom_option.state = custom_option.state ^ QStyle::State_HasFocus;

        if (option.state.testFlag(QStyle::State_Selected)) 
        {
            custom_option.palette.setBrush(QPalette::Normal, QPalette::Highlight, QBrush(Qt::red));
        }

        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, custom_option, index);
    }
};
```

Код учитывал две строки и два цвета, но... результат был вот такой:

[image: Неправильное выделение]

Почему выделяется не вся строка, я не знаю...

Вот тут описана похожая проблема https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255224/changing-the-row-background-color-of-a-qtreeview-does-not-work

И на основании предложенных там кусочков кода я решил переопределить метод drawRow

```
void drawRow(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const override
{
    QStyleOptionViewItem custom_option(option);

    if (custom_option.state.testFlag(QStyle::State_HasFocus))
        custom_option.state = custom_option.state ^ QStyle::State_HasFocus;

    if (selectionModel()->isRowSelected(left_row, left.parent()))
    {
        custom_option.palette.setBrush(QPalette::Normal, QPalette::Highlight, Qt::red);
    }
    else if (selectionModel()->isRowSelected(right_row, right.parent()))
    {
        custom_option.palette.setBrush(QPalette::Normal, QPalette::Highlight, Qt::green);
    }

    QTreeView::drawRow(painter, custom_option, index);
}

void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *_event) override
{
    QTreeView::mousePressEvent(_event);

    auto index = indexAt(_event->pos());
    auto item = itemAt(_event->pos());

    if (index.isValid() && item->childCount() == 0) //bottom level
    {
        if (_event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
        {
            left = index;
            left_row = left.row();
        }
        else if (_event->button() == Qt::RightButton)
        {
            right = index;
            right_row = right.row();
        }
    }

    selectionModel()->clearSelection();
    QItemSelection selected_items;
    selected_items.select(left, left);
    selected_items.select(right, right);
    selectionModel()->select(selected_items, QItemSelectionModel::Rows | QItemSelectionModel::Select);
}
```

Сразу скажу, что `custom_option.state.testFlag(QStyle::State_HasFocus))` в данном случае не работает, что уже плохо. Вообще QStyle::State_HasFocus и QStyle::State_Selected почему-то не выставлены. Данный способ работает тоже кривовато. Обе строки выделяются одним цветом, рамка фокуса присутствует и вообще есть всякие глюки, но зато строка выделяется полностью.

[image: Нет описания]

Вопрос собственно в том, каким способом лучше делать (чтобы железобетонно всё работало как задумано) и на что следует обратить внимание? По какому принципу идентифицировать строки? Всё-таки номер строки здесь относительно родительского элемента. Я проковырялся целый день на этой нелепости и чувствую сегодняшний тоже буду ковыряться. Пока буду ковыряться, буду ждать замечаний от вас =)

Спасибо заранее!

Qt 5.7

Comment: Свой model/view и есть решение по-проще.